# Export TODOs in Android Studio/IntelliJ

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, todo

I have a project with a bunch of TODOs.

Is there any way to export all the TODOs from project to some file?

Is there any feature/trick/plugin to achieve this in Android Studio/IntelliJ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no special action to export todo list, but in IntelliJ you can [run](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-inspection-by-name.html) the "TODO comment" inspection, and [export the inspection results](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/exporting-inspection-results.html).